# ItemContainerGenerator returns null, why?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<ListBox BorderThickness="0" x:Name="PendingChatListBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Height="40" Click="OpenChat_click" Content="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True, Converter={StaticResource cPendingUnreadMessagesConverter}}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" x:Name="OpenChatButton" Foreground="Blue"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

```
ObservableCollection<SideBarUnit> OpenChats = new ObservableCollection<SideBarUnit>();
this.PendingChatListBox.ItemsSource = OpenChats;


if (PendingChatListBox.Items.Count > 0)
{
    // WHY IS THIS OBJECT NULL?
    object obj = PendingChatListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(PendingChatListBox.Items[0]); 
}
```

Comment: I would recommend *not* using the `ItemContainerGenerator` at all, use data bindng if you need to change any properties.

Comment: Doesn't help that your list is empty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because of virtualization, items out of view have no container generated for them (if the items panel is virtualizing in nature; default for ListBoxes and the like).

Or if you assign a source and try to get the container in the same method the ListBox did not have the time to create it yet. The UI-thread must idle to do so.

Comment: Is there a way to force the UI thread to create it - if I did want to keep everything in the same function?  Just wondering.

Comment: @iterationx: I don't know of any, the `ItemContainerGenerator` raises a [`StatusChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.statuschanged.aspx) though which could be helpful as it may tell you when the container has been generated.